# dhtmlx column is not sorting

Tags: dhtmlx

```
        mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('mygrid_container');
        mygrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/");
        mygrid.setHeader("Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col1=7");
        mygrid.setInitWidths("*,*,*,*,*,*,*");
        **mygrid.setColAlign("left,left,left,left,left,left,left");**
        mygrid.setSkin("light");

        mygrid.setColSorting("str, int, int, int, int, int, int");
        mygrid.init();
```

I have this working and sorting on the first column but I get the sorting caret for all of the other columns but the rows don't sort. I am looking at the console with firebug but I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

WRONG

```
mygrid.setColSorting("str, int, int, int, int, int, int");'
```

Remove the spaces.

RIGHT

```
mygrid.setColSorting("str,int,int,int,int,int,int");
```